# How can I have bigger imageview for larger screen size layout?

Tags: android

I am looking at my android design for medium and large screen. I have designed my layout for mdeium screen (viewing it on the eclipse editor and emulator) and making sure it is good. My design involves textview and images view. I have create the 3 drawable folders for different density sizes so the picture can occupies the rough space on different densities.

Now, I am looking at the large screens (and even xtra large screens) but my textviews and images views looks very small (compared to the size of the screen). Therefore  I would like to make use ofd the extra space by enlarging everything.

I know how to do it for text views, basically I would make textsize bigger (ie. instead of 12 sp I can make it 16sp)

But How can I do it for ImageView? The Imageview displays the image according to its size. And the size of the image is really meant for medium screen. How can I make it bigger? Should I provide the same image  with a bigger size and a different name?

Please help, btw plz dont point me to the android develoment supporting mutliple screens cause I read it and I couldn't find what I need unless I missed a certain line that answers my question.
Thank you for your help

Decided to edit the question maybe people can understand my question more.
I have an image that is 50 X 50 pix in medium density medium screen size. Let say that this image occupies 5 by 5 millimeters, Now if I want to display the same image on medium desnity XLARGE screen but I want it to be bigger (say occupies 10 by 10 millimters). How do I achieve that? I understand  I wil lneed different layout in the XLARGE folder so in this layout what should I do with that image view? Do I create a new PNG file with 100X100 pix and place it in the medium density folder?

Comment: may be this can solve your problem `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Comment: Are you defining things with device independent pixel sizes?  I haven't used these before, but I am sure this is exactly what they are for.

Comment: fitXY will stretch the imageview to fit the image and thats not my problem, the problem that the image being referenced is already to small for big size. How can I stretch the IMAGE itself

Comment: My image view is all wrap_content, so no DP is involved

Comment: @Snake Have you got the answer? I have same problem in designing the layout for 5 inch and 7 inch. Both the screen sizes comes under `layout-large` . Suppose I have a `ImageView`, How should i manage height and width .I have tried with using `dp` but not wworking for both. How should I manage ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use layout-xhdpi ,layout-hdpi etc..as per your requirement.

Comment: this still has not answered my question. I know about the layout folders. Even if I have a different layout, the SAME image is still references therefore the same size will be occupied

Comment: no i think you can define a bigger image(even different) and give different parameters for height and width and can even have a totally new layout.

Comment: So when you give higher values for height and width, will the image stretch to match these values

Answer (score 0):

All of your screen xml files can be placed in multiple folders (layout, layout-large, layout-xlarge, etc.) in which you can scale the size of the UI components in DPI based upon the size of the screen. See Android documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: this still has not answered my question. I know about the layout folders. Even if  I have a different layout, the SAME image is still references therefore the same size will be occupied

Comment: @Snake Have you got the answer? I have same problem in designing the layout for 5 inch and 7 inch. Both the screen sizes comes under `layout-large` . Suppose I have a ImageView, How should i manage height and width .I have tried with using `dp`  but not wworking for both. How should i manage?